# REST Query Language with RSQL for Date fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm implementing a query search on a model following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-rsql-fiql?utm_source=email-newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=auto_61_rest&tl_inbound=1&tl_target_all=1&tl_period_type=3) :

Now everything is working fine but I have a big issue on a date field. When I try to query on the date i get the error:

```
Parameter value [1965-01-01] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1965-01-01] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
```

How can I make it work?

--- EDIT

This is my stacktrace when the error happens

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2019-01-01] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler$1$1.bind(CriteriaCompiler.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:368) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3702) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:632) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:609) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:377) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.montedelgallo.openpacorespring.controllers.AnagraficaController.findAllByRsql(AnagraficaController.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

--- EDIT 2

this is the code from AnagraficaController.findAllByRsql

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/cerca")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Anagrafica> findAllByRsql(@RequestBody @Valid SearchPatternRequest requests) {

        if (requests.getSearchPattern() != null) {
            Node rootNode = new RSQLParser().parse(requests.getSearchPattern());
            Specification<Anagrafica> spec = rootNode.accept(new CustomRsqlVisitor<Anagrafica>());
            return repository.findAll(spec);
        } else {
            return repository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

Also if it can be helpful this is the search pattern:
"lastname==ALF*;dob>2019-01-01"

--- Edit 3

CustomRsqlVisitor looks like this:

```
public class CustomRsqlVisitor<T> implements RSQLVisitor<Specification<T>, Void> {

    private GenericRsqlSpecBuilder<T> builder;

    public CustomRsqlVisitor() {
        builder = new GenericRsqlSpecBuilder<T>();
    }

    @Override
    public Specification<T> visit(final AndNode node, final Void param) {
        return builder.createSpecification(node);
    }

    @Override
    public Specification<T> visit(final OrNode node, final Void param) {
        return builder.createSpecification(node);
    }

    @Override
    public Specification<T> visit(final ComparisonNode node, final Void params) {
        return builder.createSpecification(node);
    }

}
```

--- Edit 4

GenericRsqlSpecBuilder here:

```
public class GenericRsqlSpecBuilder<T> {

    public Specification<T> createSpecification(final Node node) {
        if (node instanceof LogicalNode) {
            return createSpecification((LogicalNode) node);
        }
        if (node instanceof ComparisonNode) {
            return createSpecification((ComparisonNode) node);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Specification<T> createSpecification(final LogicalNode logicalNode) {

        List<Specification<T>> specs = logicalNode.getChildren()
                .stream()
                .map(node -> createSpecification(node))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Specification<T> result = specs.get(0);
        if (logicalNode.getOperator() == LogicalOperator.AND) {
            for (int i = 1; i < specs.size(); i++) {
                result = Specification.where(result).and(specs.get(i));
            }
        }
        else if (logicalNode.getOperator() == LogicalOperator.OR) {
            for (int i = 1; i < specs.size(); i++) {
                result = Specification.where(result).or(specs.get(i));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Specification<T> createSpecification(final ComparisonNode comparisonNode) {
        return Specification.where(new GenericRsqlSpecification<T>(comparisonNode.getSelector(), comparisonNode.getOperator(), comparisonNode.getArguments()));
    }

}
```

--- EDIT 5

GenericRsqlSpecification Class

```
public class GenericRsqlSpecification<T> implements Specification<T> {

    private String property;
    private ComparisonOperator operator;
    private List<String> arguments;

    public GenericRsqlSpecification(final String property, final ComparisonOperator operator, final List<String> arguments) {
        super();
        this.property = property;
        this.operator = operator;
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<T> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        final List<Object> args = castArguments(root);
        final Object argument = args.get(0);
        switch (RsqlSearchOperation.getSimpleOperator(operator)) {

            case EQUAL: {
                if (argument instanceof String) {
                    return builder.like(root.get(property), argument.toString().replace('*', '%'));
                } else if (argument == null) {
                    return builder.isNull(root.get(property));
                } else {
                    return builder.equal(root.get(property), argument);
                }
            }
            case NOT_EQUAL: {
                if (argument instanceof String) {
                    return builder.notLike(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString().replace('*', '%'));
                } else if (argument == null) {
                    return builder.isNotNull(root.get(property));
                } else {
                    return builder.notEqual(root.get(property), argument);
                }
            }
            case GREATER_THAN: {
                return builder.greaterThan(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString());
            }
            case GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL: {
                return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString());
            }
            case LESS_THAN: {
                return builder.lessThan(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString());
            }
            case LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL: {
                return builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString());
            }
            case IN:
                return root.get(property).in(args);
            case NOT_IN:
                return builder.not(root.get(property).in(args));
        }

        return null;
    }

    // === private

    private List<Object> castArguments(final Root<T> root) {

        final Class<? extends Object> type = root.get(property).getJavaType();

        final List<Object> args = arguments.stream().map(arg -> {
            if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
                return Integer.parseInt(arg);
            } else if (type.equals(Long.class)) {
                return Long.parseLong(arg);
            } else {
                return arg;
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return args;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Added the stacktrace

Comment: I can't see any stacktrace?

Comment: It should be visible now

Comment: Thanks. Please add the code from .AnagraficaController.findAllByRsql

Comment: I added that code and also the search pattern I am using to query results

Comment: How does SearchPatternRequest look like?

Comment: it's actually a json body in the request:
so the class SearchPatternRequest has only a property which is searchPattern .    
{
 "searchPattern":"cognome==ALF*;datanas>2019-01-01"
}

Comment: Ok an how does CustomRsqlVisitor look like?

Comment: Edited the question and added CustomRsqlVisitor

Comment: And what is GenericRsqlSpecBuilder? In this builder the conversion to Date should happen

Comment: I added the GenericRsqlSpecBuilder class in the question. I'm so grateful to you for all this time you are spending for my issue :)

Comment: And GenericRsqlSpecification?

Comment: added GenericRsqlSpecification

Comment: So there is no type conversion. You have to add some type conversion if it's not a String. Otherwise the date is handled as a string as well.